# TabBar con Mapa en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo un problema al agregar un mapa dentro del TapBar, cuando intento desplazarme dentro del mapa hacia la derecha o izquierda se desplaza es el tapbar. Como puedo evitarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el `Scroll` del parent está interceptando los eventos del `child` que sería el `GoogleMap` widget.

Para solucionar esto lo que debes hacer es quitar el scroll del `TabBarView` cuando estés en la pestaña del mapa, ya que no muestras código voy a poner lo necesario.

Suponiendo que estás usando el `DefaultTabController` widget :

```
    TabController _tabController;

   @override
    void initState() {
      _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
      _tabController.addListener(
        () {
          setState(() {});
        },
      );
      super.initState();
    }



    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return DefaultTabController(
               length: 2,
               ....
```

Cuando agregues el `TabBarView` debes poner una condicional en la propiedad de `physics` :

```
     return TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                physics: _tabController.index == 0
                    ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                    : AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  GoogleMap(   
                     ...),

                     AnotherWidgetHere() 
                     ] 
                     ....
```

Comment: Excelente diego ..!! muchas graciias. :D